# Not linear Recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve recursion:$$a_{n+1}=a_n-a_n\cdot a_{n+1}$$. I tried transforming this recursion in form $$a_{n+1}=\frac{pa_n+q}{ra_n+s}$$ and then solve it as linear recursion. But not sure how to do it. Also not sure is there useful substitution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If you call
$b_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$
you get the recursion
$$b_{n+1} = b_n +1$$